# SAPUI5_JSON Data binding issue

Tags: sapui5

I'm trying to bind a local JSON data(in file) to a `<SELECT>`/`<ComboBox>` element, I could see the data being pulled by the server. However, the data is not getting bound to element. Please help.

--- Controller

```js
sap.ui.define([
        'jquery.sap.global',
        'sap/ui/core/mvc/Controller',
        'sap/ui/model/json/JSONModel'
    ], function(jQuery, Controller, JSONModel) {
    "use strict";

    var PageController = Controller.extend("survey.App", {

        onInit: function () {
            var oModel = new JSONModel(jQuery.sap.getModulePath("sap", "/products.json"));
            this.getView().setModel(oModel);
            console.log(oModel);
        }
    });
    return PageController;

   });
```

-- XML VIEW

```js
<mvc:View
height="100%"
controllerName="survey.App"
xmlns:core="sap.ui.core"
xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc"
xmlns="sap.m">
<Page showHeader="true">
    <content>
        <ComboBox id="prodlist"
                items="{
                    path: '/ProductCollection',
                    sorter: { path: 'Name' }
                }">
                <core:Item key="{ProductId}" text="{Name}" />
        </ComboBox>
        <!-- <Select
                items="{
                    path: '/ProductCollection',
                    sorter: { path: 'Name' }
                }">
                <core:Item key="{ProductId}" text="{Name}" />
            </Select> -->    
    </content>
</Page>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check your console an see if there is a 404 for the json file that you try to load via

```
jQuery.sap.getModulePath("sap", "/products.json")
```

The issue might be related to wrong resource-roots settings in the bootstrapping, which you have not posted...

[This here](https://jsbin.com/duribonime/edit?html,output) is a working example. As you can see I'm not using jQuery.sap.getModulePath(...), instead I use the URL directly. I works just fine for me. Maybe there is also CORS issue in your case, which my example does not have because I just use cors-anywere. Again, nobody can tell you more before you post the complete code including the bootstrap!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>SAPUI5 single file template | nabisoft</title>
        <script src="https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js"
            id="sap-ui-bootstrap"
            data-sap-ui-theme="sap_bluecrystal"
            data-sap-ui-libs="sap.m"
            data-sap-ui-bindingSyntax="complex"
            data-sap-ui-compatVersion="edge"
            data-sap-ui-preload="async"></script>
            <!-- use "sync" or change the code below if you have issues -->
    
        <!-- XMLView -->
        <script id="myXmlView" type="ui5/xmlview">
            <mvc:View
                controllerName="MyController"
                xmlns="sap.m"
                xmlns:core="sap.ui.core"
                xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc">
    
                <ComboBox 
                    id="prodlist"
                    items="{
                        path: '/ProductCollection',
                        sorter: { path: 'Name' }
                    }">
                    <core:Item key="{ProductId}" text="{Name}" />
                </ComboBox>
    
            </mvc:View>
        </script>
    
        <script>
            sap.ui.getCore().attachInit(function () {
                "use strict";
    
                //### Controller ###
                sap.ui.controller("MyController", {
                    onInit : function () {
    
                        // set explored app's demo model on this sample
                        var oModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel("https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/openui5.hana.ondemand.com/test-resources/sap/ui/demokit/explored/products.json");
                        this.getView().setModel(oModel);
    
                    }
                });
    
                //### THE APP: place the XMLView somewhere into DOM ###
                sap.ui.xmlview({
                    viewContent : jQuery("#myXmlView").html()
                }).placeAt("content");
    
            });
        </script>
    
    </head>
    
    <body class="sapUiBody">
        <div id="content"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment, The Code i've posted is a working one, however the problem is with the verison of SAPUI5 library. I was referring to 1.32.5 where below code doesnt work i.e., path & sorter attributes aren't supported.

    'items="{
      path: '/ProductCollection',
      sorter: { path: 'Name' }
     }'

Comment: @venkat that's not true, it should also work with 1.32.5. You should have posted the complete code that does not work, including the bootstrap.

Comment: Yes dear friend, you're right...:) I missed the binding type declaration in Index.html "data-sap-ui-xx-bindingSyntax="complex"". Well, i'm picking up sapui5 concepts day by day, realized about that recently. Thank you.

Comment: @Venkat It's great to see you make progress day by day - keep on coding with UI5!